# More Than One Activity

Tags: android, user-interface

I need more than one activity, more than one layout. So how do I write my XML?

Comment: Don't understand your question. Could you specify a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [`Notepad`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) application provided with the android sdk. In this application there is multiple activities (`NoteEditor` and `NotesList` for example) and multiple layouts (`note_editor.xml`, ...).
If this doesn't help, feel free to ask for a more specific question (for instance what XML are you talking about).

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Android Documentation on Activity's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html).